# Can't create NSRegularExpression because of "Couldn't create (Metatype) escape NSRegularExpression"

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to create the following `NSRegularExpression` (I'm trying to find all commas `,`, left-parens `(`, right-parens `)`, and backslashes `\`):

```
var error: NSError?
NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[,\\(\\)\\]", options: nil, error: &error)
```

But it returns `.None` with the following error:

```
Couldn't create (Metatype) escape NSRegularExpression
```

And the following `userInfo`:

```
NSInvalidValue: "[,\(\)\]"
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My backslash literal inside the character class wasn't properly escaped. It used two backslashes inside the string literal instead of four.

```
var error: NSError?
NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[,\\(\\)\\]", options: nil, error: &error)
```

Should be:

```
var error: NSError?
NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[,\\(\\)\\\\]", options: nil, error: &error)
```

I think the `Couldn't create (Metatype) escape` error refers to the incompletely escaped backslash leading to escaping the final square bracket, which makes the character class definition invalid.